# Mesh deform problem (Sphere)

Tags: animation, mesh, vertices, cloth-simulation

I have a cage and a mesh and the cage has inner edges for the cloth simulation can look more like a ball bouncing.
When I add a mesh deform to the mesh and target the cage and run the animation this happens:
**Link:** https://gyazo.com/c4b1894865cf680282ffbd4120955841

Highlighted part is the mesh.
[image]

This is the cage, you can see the inner edges.
[image]

This is the mesh by itself
[image]

Now this here is the problem see those vertex on the mesh?
**Link again:** https://gyazo.com/c4b1894865cf680282ffbd4120955841
Well when they touch the cage inner edges some reason they don't move with the cloth simulation anymore.

I need any kind of answer, right or wrong, I just need help here.

Comment: anyone? ```````